# Qual a diferença entre .prop() e .attr()?

Tags: jquery

Essas duas funções do jQuery fazem exatamente a mesma coisa? Ou há alguma diferença entre as mesmas.

É informado que a função `.prop()` veio a partir do jQuery 1.6

Ela veio para substituir `.attr()` ? Ou as duas estão presentes(e usadas) hoje na biblioteca tendo as mesmas funcionalidades para quem as deseja usar?

Comment: Da uma olhada nessas respostas é em inglês possui vários exemplos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: ótimo Gabriel! vou ver

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ambos perfazem as mesmas funções.

A diferença é que o método `.prop()` está no `DOM` e o método `.attr()` está no `HTML`.

Um exemplo, mais claro e genérico, é quando tenta acessar um atributo inexistente num elemento, poderá acessar esse atributo no DOM (usando o `.prop()`), porém, esse atributo está sempre vazio por padrão. Se acessa pelo método `.attr()`, retorna como `undefined`.

Exemplo:

```js
v = $("#foo").prop("class");
console.debug("prop retorna vazio: "+v);
v = $("#foo").attr("class");
console.debug("attr retorna indefinido: "+v);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">bar</div>
```

Veja o resultado pelo console no developer tools. No chrome, pressione Ctrl+Shift+I e clique na guia "console".

Resultará nisso:

```
   prop retorna vazio: 
   attr retorna indefinido: undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

Depende da situação, na verdade o .prop() trás o valor, literalmente e o .attr() o conteúdo, por exemplo:

```html
 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
```

```js
$('input').prop('checked'); //Retorna true
$('input').attr('checked'); //Retorna checked
```

Na página do jquery isso é explicado com mais detalhes(inglês).
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: hum... interessante, eu só usava attr(), não sabia o que o prop() fazia...
Você disse que depende da situação, pode haver algum caso em que os dois farão a mesma coisa?

Comment: Na verdade não é que faça a mesma coisa, mas o resultado é o mesmo, quando você precisa do "value" de um elemento por exemplo...

Comment: Ótimo exemplo. O .prop() busca pelo DOM, e para o DOM, o checked é um booleano. Por isso retorna true ou false. O .attr() vai pelo HTML e retorna o conteúdo, no caso, retorna "checked" como uma string. Enfim, fazem praticamente as mesmas coisas com pequenas diferenças. A maior diferença que é bem clara é, um atua no DOM e outro no HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1º) ATRIBUTO -  Quando você escreve o HTML, chamamos de atributo do HTML

```
HTML
<input type="checkbox" />

    type é o atributo      "checkbox" é o conteúdo 

    jquery pegando o atributo
        $('input').attr('type'); //retorna 'checkbox'
        $('input').attr('checked'); //retorna 'undefined'(porque você não
                                    //digitou o atributo checked = "checked"  no input, 
                                    //então ele não existe lá)
```

2º) PROPRIEDADE - Quando você chama o objeto input, encontram-se as propriedades

```
HTML
<input type="checkbox" />

    type é o atributo      "checkbox" é o conteúdo 


    a) Mostrando o objeto input com jquery    

        console.log($("input"));
            quando você fizer este console verá que muitas propriedades aparecerão, 
            porem vou mostrar somente duas no exemplo abaixo 

            OBJETO
                input
                   type   : "checkbox", (type    é a propriedade - "checkbox" é o valor)
                   checked: false       (checked é a propriedade - false      é o valor)

    b) Jquery pegando a propriedade
        $('input').prop('type');    //retorna o valor 'checkbox'
        $('input').prop('checked'); //retorna o valor 'false'
```

RESUMO

```
        ATRIBUTO    .attr() você pega da escrita HTML <input type="checkbox" />
        PROPRIEDADE .prop() você pega do OBJETO input
```