# Checkbox selecionado na função

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma função e estou tentando setar o checkbox como true, na função, desta forma:

```js
 $("#cbpre").checked = true;
```

Porém ele não está marcando, já depurei, e ele entra nesta parte, apenas não marca o checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
 
  $("#cbpre").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cbpre"" type="checkbox">
```

**OU**

[**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
 $("#cbpre").attr('checked','checked')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cbpre"" type="checkbox">
```

[**Qual a diferença entre .prop() e .attr()?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116204/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-prop-e-attr)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método `attr` ou o método `prop` do JQuery para isso:

```js
$('#ck1').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('#ck2').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   Checkbox 1: <input id='ck1' type="checkbox" />
</p>
<p>
   Checkbox 2: <input id='ck2' type="checkbox" />
</p>
```