# Alterar o tipo de campo de entrada com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
    $('#password').val('Password');
});
```

Isso deve alterar o `#password` campo de entrada (com `id="password"`) de `type` `password` campo de texto normal e, em seguida, preencher o texto "`Password`".

Não funciona. Por quê?

Aqui está o formulário:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/auth/sign-in">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="element">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Prihlasovacie meno" class="input-text" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="element">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="input-text" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="sign_in" id="sign_in" value="Prihlásiť" class="input-submit" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: Não ficou claro sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu quero alterar o tipo do input de password para text com jquery.

Comment: Qual versão jQuery está usando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 3.3.1.

Comment: [Resposta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116215/6333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código não funcionou com **attr** pq você está utilizando a versão atual do **jQuery 3.3.1** que utiliza o **prop** para trabalhar com atributos o **attr** era usado até a versões **1.6**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#password').prop('type', 'text');
    $('#password').val('Password');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/auth/sign-in">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="element">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Prihlasovacie meno" class="input-text" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="element">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="input-text" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="sign_in" id="sign_in" value="Prihlásiť" class="input-submit" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

> Para saber mais pode ver [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)